# How to add a custom command in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager, sbt-release

I'm trying to add a new command to my sbt.

In my `build.sbt` I have

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(mySuperDuperCommand)
```

In a sibling file `mySuperDuperCommands.sbt` I have

```
lazy val mySuperDuperTaskKey = TaskKey[Unit]("mySuperDuperCommand")

lazy val mySuperDuperCommand := { ... do *amazing* stuff ... }
```

It gives me the error `cannot resolve symbol "mySuperDuperCommand"` inside `build.sbt`. How to solve this conondrum?

Comment: Did you try to locate mySuperDuperCommands.sbt under project directory instead?

Comment: @P3trur0 I got error: not found: value mySuperDuperCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to stay with a single build file then, in your `build.sbt` you can do:

```
lazy val mySuperDuperTask = TaskKey[Unit]("mySuperDuperCommand")
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(mySuperDuperTask:= { ... })
```

of course by replacing `...` with your own task implementation.

Alternatively, if you prefer to use two different files you can do something like this:

In `project/Build.scala` you can define your Task. For example:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ProjectBuild {
    lazy val mySuperDuperTask = TaskKey[Unit]("mySuperDuperCommand", "Prints hello.")
    def buildSettings = Seq(mySuperDuperTask:={println("Hello")})
}
```

Then, in your `build.sbt` you can write:

```
import ProjectBuild._
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(ProjectBuild.buildSettings : _*)
```

Then you can invoke your proper `sbt mySuperDuperCommand`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So no way to put it in a separate file?

Comment: Yes, in my example you should stay just with build.sbt. However, if you prefer, you can make that in two separate files too.

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
lazy val mySuperDuperCommand := { ... do *amazing* stuff ... }
```

is wrong. `:=` is a function that creates a SettingDefinition. Change the line to

```
lazy val mySuperDuperCommand: Def.SettingsDefinition = { 
  mySuperDuperTaskKey := { ... do *amazing* stuff ... }
}
```

and it should work.